# Export SailsJS model schema as JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sails.js

The goal is to take model schema and export it somewhere as JSON, take that json and make a dynamic form in Angular.

Basically main problem which I see here is to get model, and generate output which will be important for generating reactive form in Angular.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    nameOnMenu: { type: 'string', required: true },
    price: { type: 'string', required: true },
    percentRealMeat: { type: 'number' },
    numCalories: { type: 'number' },
  },
};
```

So final output would look like:

```
[
  { nameOnMenu: { type: 'string', required: true }},
  { price: { type: 'string', required: true }},
  { percentRealMeat: { type: 'number',  required: false }},
  { numCalories: { type: 'number', required: false }},
]
```

Based on this output, i will go through all and generate form.

Comment: did you give it any try ?

Comment: Just use fs and for attribute in "attributes" in this file write and object in array as you want and than JSON.stringify and save the file. EDIT: you actually don't need fs - you can require this file

Comment: @GeorgeBailey i am researching more about it, reading sails docs and trying to find a solution.

Comment: @KrešimirGalić you won't find an oficial solution, however in scope inside controllers you may have access to inner sails variables simply console.log (this).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I really understand the question that you are asking here but let me take a bash at trying to provide an answer.

I can think of two ways that you could achieve it:

1.) Use [server rendered local data](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/locals) to include the desired result for use on the front end.

2.) Make [an API request](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/io-socket-get) from the front end for the desired result.

In your resulting controller/action you can get the model attributes in various ways. I can think of one:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
// Portable relative path based on code being in
// config/bootstrap.js file so adjust as required
const modelDefinition = require(resolve(__dirname, '..', 'api', 'models', 'NameOfModel.js')).attributes;
console.log(modelDefinition);
{ name:
  { type: 'string',
    required: true,
    validations: { isNotEmptyString: true },
    autoMigrations:
     { columnType: 'varchar(255)',
       unique: false,
       autoIncrement: false } },
  ...etc,
}
```

For completeness, you would need to factor in a few things regarding the [model settings](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings) and [model attributes](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) in order to get an accurate output, for instance, whether or not the table includes an updatedAt field.

Ultimately, you can marshal this data as you see fit with vanilla Javascript/Node in order to obtain your desired result but I will leave that to you.

As another user has pointed out, I'm also not sure that you will find an officially supported solution for completely reactive data using Angular and Sails, I assume that this will require a bit of engineering in order for your to create something that is suitable for your needs.